# In R: How do I increment a column value based on multiples of a certain value in the adjacent column

Tags: r, repeat, cumsum

I'm quite new to R, unfortunately I wasn't able to find help in other related questions so far.

I have this dataframe called selection, including column 'RUN' and column 'TRNO'.
[image: Selection dataframe]

It originally had 9 columns. I added the column 'RUN' which contains a count that increases by 1 whenever the value in the column 'DAP' is 0, using this code:

```
# Insert column RUN in "selection" dataframe

library(dplyr)

selection$RUN <- cumsum(selection$DAP == 0)
```

That worked perfectly. Now I would like to do a similar operation for the column 'TRNO'. It also needs to contain a count that this time only increases when the column 'RUN' arrives at multiples of 80 (i.e. from RUN == 1-80 --> count =1; RUN == 81-160 --> count =2,...)

I tried several codes, amongst others this one:

```
# Insert column TRNO in "selection" dataframe

i = 0

repeat{

   i = i+80

   selection$TRNO <- cumsum(selection$RUN == i)

   break

 }
```

Instead of increasing the count at every multiple of 80, it returns "0" when RUN values are between 1-80, increases to 92 when RUN values are at 80, and then stagnates at 92 for all the higher values in RUN.

[image: Selection edataframe including column 'RUN' and column 'TRNO]

Comment: Would you be so kind and replace images with snippets of text?

Comment: Please use `dput(selection)` to create output that can be used to recreate your data. Copy and paste the output from the R console into a code chunk in your post.

Comment: Looking at your screenshots I just saw, that your data has 1 Million rows, with `dput(head(selection, 250))` you can create code for a dataframe that contains the first 250 rows only, that should be more adequate for sharing.

Comment: I was playing around with dput(), but the problem was I needed at least 1700 rows to properly display it. Now the question was answered already, but I know dput() for the next time. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
selection$TRONO <- ceiling(selection$RUN/80)
```